# gnu parallel one job per processor

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc, gnu-parallel, torque

I am trying to use gnu parallel GNU parallel (version 20160922)
to launch a large number of protein docking jobs (using UCSF Dock 6.7).  I am running on a high performance cluster with several dozen nodes each with 28-40 cores.  The system is running CentOS 7.1.1503, and uses torque for job management.

I am trying to submit each config file in dock.n.d to the dock executable, one per core on the cluster.  Here is my PBS file:

```
#PBS -l walltime=01:00:00
#PBS -N pardock
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=28
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -o /home/path/to/pardock.log

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cat $PBS_NODEFILE temp.txt
#f=$(pwd)
ls dock.in.d/*.in | parallel -j 300 --sshloginfile $PBS_NODEFILE  "/path/to/local/bin/dock6 -i {} -o {}.out"
```

This works fine on a single node as written above.  But when I scale up to, say, 300 processors (with `-l procs=300`) accross several nodes I begin to get these errors:

```
parallel: Warning: ssh to node026 only allows for 99 simultaneous logins.
parallel: Warning: You may raise this by changing /etc/ssh/sshd_config:MaxStartups and MaxSessions on node026.
```

What I do not understand is why there are so many logins.  Each node only has 28-40 cores so, as specified in $PBS_NODEFILE, I would expect there to only be 28-40 SSH logins at any point in time on these nodes.

Am I misunderstanding or misexecuting something here?  Please advise what other information I can provide or what direction I should go to get this to work.

**UPDATE**

So my problem above was the combination of `-j 300` and the use of `$PBS_NODEFILE`, which has a separate entry for each core on each node.  So in that case it seems I should used `-j 1`.  But then, all the jobs seem to run on a single node.

So my question remains, how to get gnu parallel to balance the jobs between nodes, utilizing all cores, but not creating an excessive number of SSH logins due to multiple jobs per core.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are asking GNU Parallel to ignore the number of cores and run 300 jobs on each server.

Try instead:

```
ls dock.in.d/*.in | parallel --sshloginfile $PBS_NODEFILE  /path/to/local/bin/dock6 -i {} -o {}.out
```

This will default to `--jobs 100%` which is one job per core on all machines.

If you are not allowed to use all cores on the machines, you can in prepend `X/` to the hosts in `--sshloginfile` to force X as the number of cores:

```
28/server1.example.com
20/server2.example.com
16/server3.example.net
```

This will force GNU Parallel to skip the detection of cores, and instead use 28, 20, and 16 respectively. This combined with `-j 100%` can control how many jobs you want started on the different servers.

Comment: I gave this a try, and parallel seems not to distinguish between cores on the machine and cores assigned to ME on the machine.  For example, if I request 20 cores on a 28 core node, I start to see well over 20 dock6 jobs.  (approaching the total number of cores on the node).  Is their a way to tell parallel to abide by the core limit (for example, as represented by the number of entries each node has in $PBS_NODEFILE)?  Or is this Undocumented Behavior (tm) or User Error (tm)?